# Selenium C# to disable Microsoft Chromium Edge browser Sync pop-up

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge, chromium

I am trying to test automate my application website using selenium and C# on Chromium Edge browser (version  83.0.478.45).
Every time the chromium edge driver opens up browser, it displays a pop up for sync as shown in picture below. Is there any way to stop it?

EdgeOptions used:

```
options.UseChromium = true;
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
options.AddArguments("--disable-web-security");
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to launch the browser in private mode? If no, then you can have a try to test it and let us know about the results. edgeOptions.addArguments("-inprivate");

Comment: Ok, it does not pop up in Inprivate mode. Is there any setting for normal mode?

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether it shows this message with your default profile when you manually launch the browser? If not then you can try to launch the browser using the default profile. Let me know, I can help to provide the sample code.

Comment: It does not pop up when I manually open the browser.

Comment: Try with this code. edgeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");

Comment: Getting Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir'

Comment: Please close all the instances of the Edge browser before running this code. Then try to run the code.

Comment: cool, works, but would be useful to have some argument which works when other instance of edge are opened.

Comment: also it has dependency to add local path - C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data.. which is not suitable for running tests in CI-CD. Any alternatives?

Comment: Actually, that profile is used by the already opened instance. so selenium code cant uses it. If you are not logged in the Edge browser then try to login with any account and turn on the sync option. then again try to run the code without using the default profile. See whether it works or not. If you think that using the default profile option can help to solve your issue then I can post it as an answer. You can try to accept the answer. Let me know about it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Few observations-
I am using Microsoft.Edge.Selenium.Tools nuget for Chromium Edge Automation using Selenium.
1. I have to manually paste msedgedriver.exe into bin folder to make it work. Is there any nuget available which will add the msedgedriver.exe on building soliution? Chromedriver nuget does it automatically on build for chromedriver.exe.
2. I logged in to Edge browser and turned on sync and kept one instance opened. I commented code for defauIt profile, it again started showing up the pop up.

Comment: The tools you download using NuGet will help to develop the automation code. You can download and place the web driver exe anywhere on your machine. You just need to reference its path in the code. I not aware about any NuGet package that can download and place the web driver in the bin folder. What result did you get with the last suggestion for logging in with an account? Is that work for you?

Comment: No, I logged in to Edge browser and turned on sync and kept one instance opened. I commented code for defauIt profile, it again started showing up the pop up.

Comment: In that situation, I think that best solution would be to launch the browser in private mode.  Let me know, whether this approach is suitable for you.

Comment: I've added a code to get default user profile using var userDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");. And it worked for me.

Comment: I will post it as an answer. Please try to accept it. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, You can try to launch the MS Edge browser using a default profile that can help you to fix this issue.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;
namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class edgewebdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
            edgeOptions.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");
            var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\webdriver";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("<website url>");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code that modified by op.

```
var userDataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");
```